# How do I add a JWT scope when generating a JWT token from a service account

Tags: grpc

I am currently using the [gRPC C++ library](https://github.com/grpc/grpc) version 1.28.3.

I create a credentials object from a service account JSON string by calling [ServiceAccountJWTAccessCredentials](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/namespacegrpc.html#a92a9f959d6102461f66ee973d8e9d3aa).

However according to some [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/region?hl=tr#api) I need to add a JWT scope after creating the credentials object if I want to select a region.

Looking at the [gRPC documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/) I see several examples for adding a JWT scope to the credentials object in Java, Go, Python... etc. but none for C++.

**My question is: Is it possible to add a JWT scope to the credentials object in C++?**